# TFS2015 vNext build: Custom step to get sources

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

The first step in any vNext TFS build is a Get Sources step which is executing the **tf get** command.

I'd like to replicate this functionality in a different build step: I need to retrieve specific files/folders on a specific conditions.

In the XAML builds I was using the Download files build activity.

How can I achieve the same behavior without installing Visual Studio and TFS PowerTools and without installing TFS Nuget packages? Just with what is installed default by the build agent.

Comment: For future reference, Jesse Houwing has been working on TFVC tasks like "Download Files" within TFS/VSTS Build vNext: https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-tfvc-tasks/issues/30#issuecomment-352868153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could run a PowerShell or a Cmd script step.
2. If you require deeper integration with the build, consider creating your own custom build task that you'd then upload to your account. Tasks logic is in PowerShell or in JavaScript.

In the later case, check out https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks for more details.

Comment: I am sorry Bogdan, but could you provide a bit more clarity? I am wanting to do this very thing, and I am not sure what task / build activity to hook into.

Comment: When you add a new task to your build definition, select "Utility" on the left and you should be able to find the Cmd task and the PowerShell task that allow you to run a script

Comment: Unfortunately Bogdan we are on TFS 2013, so I don't believe we have that available to us. Do you know how I could possibly do it with a 2013 build template?

Comment: I think I need to build a custom code activity and override the  TfGetSources code activity, but I am not sure that is the correct path.